# Meteor reactive list transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

How do I make the reordering of list items appear animated, instead of jumping suddenly?

In other words, when the score changes, items should animate into place: https://www.meteor.com/examples/leaderboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Marcos answer, I came up with a compromise-solution. Instead of moving element, I fadeOut the old and fadeIn the new. Using slideDown and slideUp, it looks pretty smooth.

```
  Template.leaderboard.rendered = function () {
this.firstNode._uihooks = {
  moveElement: function (node, next) {
    $(node).animate({ height: 'toggle', opacity: 'toggle' }, 'slow').promise().done(function(){
      $(node).insertBefore(next).animate({ height: 'toggle', opacity: 'toggle' }, 'slow');
    });
  },
};
```

};

Answer (score 6):

You should use `_uihooks` for the animations.

Add `_uihooks` to the dom element that will contain the list items.

So for the leaderboard the players are added to the tbody of the leaderboard template. Example:

```
Template.leaderboard.rendered = function () {
    this.find('tbody')._uihooks = {
        insertElement: function (node, next) {
            //insert logic
        },
        removeElement: function (node) {
            //Remove logic
        },
        moveElement: function (node) {
            //move logic
        } 
    };
};
```

Please note that when you use those hooks blaze, the responsibility for adding/removing/moving the node will be handed over the hook. So if your remove logic is bugged the node will not get removed.

It's documented [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md#blaze). Github examples: [javascript](https://github.com/gfk-ba/meteor-notifications/blob/master/notifications.js#L238-259), [coffeescript](https://github.com/mizzao/CrowdMapper/blob/master/client/views/datastream.coffee#L25-45)

Comment: interesting. This seems to be what I was looking for. However a working example on the Leaderboard example would be incredibly helpful here.

Comment: @krivar In the leaderboard you would add the _uihooks to the tbody of the leaderboard template so in Template.leaderboard.rendered you add: this.find('tbody')._uihooks ={};

Comment: this.firstNode._uihooks points to the correct container div (there is no tbody). But what do I insert into the moveElement function? Do I remove and insert into the correct place? I don't think CSS can animate that..

Comment: it is strange that moveElement does not have a 'next' parameter, as how do I know where it's trying to position the 'node'? edit: oh, it does..

Comment: I am now able to fadeOut.done(fadeIn), but it's not as good as having the divs move.

Comment: I don't see how the Github examples help answer this question.